# Deteriorating Plywood Subflooring

Tags: leak, plywood, water-damage

Here is scenario:

- House has cement foundation/slab
- An asphalt mastic was put over foundation/slab as a vapor barrier
- 5/8 inch plywood put over asphalt mastic and nailed into foundation
- Heavy plastic put over plywood
- Hardwood flooring nailed into plywood
  -- Plywood was completely soaked due to slab leak over a period of time.

We pulled up hardwood flooring (nothing wrong with hardwood floors) and most of the plywood had deteriorated to point of falling apart/mushy.

Questions:

1. How long could this plywood stay wet between the two moisture barriers?
2. How long does it typically take for plywood to deteriorate to the point of being mushy?

Comment: Plain internal plywood would probably not take long to be mushy, maybe a month or two.  Between two vapour barriers, will take a long time to dry, but it is ruin now replacement only choice.  Plywood usually has layers of real wood veneer and fake/particle wood.

Answer (score 2):

Question 1: - more or less forever, which is why you use ONE such barrier, not two. Trapping moisture between vapor barriers leads to rot...

Question 2: - depends on the quality of the plywood, the temperature, etc. can happen in months under favorable (to the rot) conditions. Could take years.